# Balanced Parenthesis challenge: Checking for string that contains no parenthesis

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did an implementation on checking if whether a string has balanced parentheses or not using a STACK only. But I checked for balanced parentheses when the string has words. For example:

```
>>> is_paren_balanced("[{whoa (this is rough [how do I do this!])}]")
True
```

I was successful in doing that. However, I am not trying to check for a case if the string has NO parenthesis. And then i got this result:

```
>>> is_paren_balanced("Hi i love food.")
no parenthesis
True
>>> is_paren_balanced("[{whoa (this is rough [how do I do this!])}]")
no parenthesis
False
```

For the first result, I don't want the boolean result as thats kind of vague. I'm trying to show the user that the string has no parenthesis so it is neither True or False. I just want the print statement shown saying "no parentheses here" or whatever. For the second result, obviously just the boolean result and it shouldve returned True.

Any suggestions? I'm stumped.

Here is the code I'm practicing with:

```
from stack import Stack

def is_match(p1, p2):
    if p1 == "(" and p2 == ")":
        return True

    elif p1 == "{" and p2 == "}":
        return True

    elif p1 == "[" and p2 == "]":
        return True

    else:
        return False


def is_paren_balanced(paren_str):
    s = Stack() #initialize a stack object
    is_balanced = True #boolean flag: whether the str has balanced parenthesis or not
    # then set to false if otherwise
    index = 0 # keep track of where we are in the string
    paren_str = paren_str.replace(" ", "") #accounts for possible spaces in the input


    while index < len(paren_str) and is_balanced:
        paren = paren_str[index]       
        if paren in "({[":
            s.push(paren)

        elif paren in ")}]":
            if s.is_empty():
                is_balanced = False

            else:
                top = s.pop()
                if not is_match(top, paren):
                    is_balanced = False

        else:
            if paren not in "({[]})":
                print("no parenthesis")
                break



        index += 1

    if s.is_empty() and is_balanced:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Sorry if it doesn't seem pythonic. I was just mostly exploring with this problem and will edit and improve later on.

Comment: how about do a check a simple if condition before the while for all the parenthesis and returning the message you want to convey to the user, if there is no parenthesis.

Comment: Or just record the maximum stack depth as you go...

Comment: I did try to do that. I tried ```if paren not in “({[]{)”``` before the while loop then “no parentheses” and so on. It just messed up all my other test cases, so with any string it just returns False whether the the string is balanced or not. And it only returns True for a string that contains no parentheses. Which of course, is wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either regex or list comprehension to get the total amount of parenthesis first:

```
import re

def all_parenthesis(msg):
    left = re.findall(r"[\[{(]",msg)
    right = re.findall(r"[\]|})]",msg)
    if not left and not right:
        return "No parenthesis"
#or

def check_balance(msg):
    d = {"[":"]",
         "{":"}",
         "(":")"}
    left = [char for char in msg if char in d]
    right = [char for char in reversed(msg) if char in d.values()]  
    #if not left not right...
```

But if you already constructed a list of parenthesis on both sides, why don't go ahead and compare them instead? Could be something like this:

```
def check_balance(msg):
    d = {"[":"]",
         "{":"}",
         "(":")"}
    left = [char for char in msg if char in d]
    right = [char for char in reversed(msg) if char in d.values()]
    if not left and not right:
        return "No parenthesis"
    elif len(left) != len(right):
        return False
    for a, b in zip(left,right):
        if d.get(a) != b:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you! Just trying to understand the second part. What did you with the ``` right ``` definition. ``` char for char in reversed(msg)...```

Comment: I was just confused about using the reversed part

Comment: Just some clarity there

Comment: The only issue with this is that. My implementation is with stacks only.

Comment: It reverses the string first before iterating. Because you are actually comparing the first and the last parenthesis , 2nd and 2nd last... so when later we use `zip` to go through both, they will match.

Comment: Oh that makes sense!

Comment: Is it possible to check in the string ha son parentheses with just stacks ?

Comment: Stacks are first in last out, so it should be even easier since you don't have to reverse the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Which I did. But for some reason even if I put the if condition outside the while loop to check for a string with no parentheses. Now the function only returns True for a string with no parentheses and returns False all the time otherwise.

Comment: For some reason I can't wrap my mind around the logic using a while loop :( but in theory it should work just like using a list by using `list.pop(-1)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197170/discussion-between-angel-baby-and-henry-yik).